# Client-side to server-side in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm having trouble with turning a client-side object into a server-side object. Below I have adapted an excerpt of my script to illustrate my problem. I want to make the end of my filter selection depend on the values of DOYend and DOYstart. Printing yearAdd and yearStr returns what I expect, but filterSelectEnd returns something I don't understand.

```
var DOYend = 10
var DOYstart = 13
var yearSelected = ee.String('2014')

    if(DOYend <= DOYstart) {
      var yearNum = ee.Number.parse(yearSelected)
      var yearAdd = yearNum.add(1)
      var yearStr = ee.String((yearAdd))
      var filterSelectEnd = ee.Algorithms.String(yearAdd + '-12-31')
    }

print('yearAdd',yearAdd)
print('yearStr',yearStr)
print('conditionResult',filterSelectEnd)
```

Output:

```
conditionResult
ee.Number({
  "type": "Invocation",
  "arguments": {
    "left": {
      "type": "Invocation",
      "arguments": {
        "input": "2015"
      },
      "functionName": "Number.parse"
    },
    "right": 1
  },
  "functionName": "Number.add"
})-12-31
```

Comment: Could you update the question with an example of the output?  A total random guess is the ( ) around '-12-13' make that a tuple which is probably NOT what you want.  Try removing the ( ).

Comment: Done, but it still hasn't solved the problem. From what I understand, filterSelectEnd has to be stated to be a server-side object, rather than a client-side. Let me add the output of 'conditionResult' as well.

Comment: See if this SO answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48411561/2258

Comment: Yep, that did it.     `if(DOYend <= DOYstart) {
      var yearNum = ee.Number.parse(yearSelected)
      var yearAdd = yearNum.add(1)
      var yearStr = ee.String(yearAdd)
      filterSelectEnd = ee.String(yearStr).cat('-12-31')
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those inputs are coming from, say a UI element, then I highly suggest keeping everything client-side:

```
var DOYend = 10
var DOYstart = 13
var yearSelected = '2014'

if(DOYend <= DOYstart) {
  var yearNum = Number(yearSelected)
  var yearAdd = yearNum + 1
  var yearStr = yearAdd + '-12-31'
}

print('yearAdd', yearAdd)
print('yearStr', yearStr)
```

(As an aside, I don't quite follow the logic here.  Shouldn't you advance the year and then advance the DOY and not set it to 12-31?  If so, that will complicate things, because now you're going to have to fiddle with either a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) or an `ee.Date`, but again, keep everything client-side if possible.)

Comment: Thanks for the insight! The objective of my script is to make a comparison for a specific date-range in a selected year with data for the same date-range for the last 36 years. I'm using sliders to determine the starts and ends of the ranges I want to look at. However, DOY is set using integers (which I am using the sliders to set), so the date range is effectively set as a count of days from the start of the year.

Answer (score 0):

See comment feed.

```
    if(DOYend <= DOYstart) { 
var yearNum = ee.Number.parse(yearSelected) 
var yearAdd = yearNum.add(1) 
var yearStr = ee.String(yearAdd) 
filterSelectEnd = ee.String(yearStr).cat('-12-31') }
```

Comment: Could maybe add some expalnations? Thanks!